# Algorithm problems - How to Modelize an A* pathfinding & Matrix in Typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, matrix, multidimensional-array, a-star

I don't speak english very well so i'm gonna try to be clear!

1. I try to make an Ionic 3 Application, so I use HTML/CSS, Angular 4 and Typescript. **(Context)**
2. I have implemented A star pathfinding algorithm following this link : https://github.com/digitsensitive/astar-typescript. **(Success)**
3. I used and transformed it, to find the shortest path from one point to another passing through multiple goals. **(Success)**
4. This is what I get : **(Success)** [image: My result]
5. Now, I'd like to modelize my matrix AND my path like this: **(To do)** [image: What I'd like]
6. I realized this with div, ngIf, CSS : **(Done)** [image: My CSS, Div & ngIf]
7. Now .. I have no idea how to put in green my path. (Like in the img of "5." ) **(To do)**

   - I'd like to access to `[x][y]` of each element of my matrix
   - Compare with `[value, value]` of myPath
   - If it is the same, color in green or something like this..

Can you help me please?

Thank you very much for reading this (long) post, Best !

Update : Here is my code to find the shortest path with multiple goals (complete code of AStar is on the github)

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { MycartProvider } from '../../providers/mycart/mycart';
import * as AStar from '../../pathfinding/aStar/main';

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-itinerary',
  templateUrl: 'itinerary.html',
})
export class ItineraryPage {

private goals=[[2, 2], [4, 4]];
private newgoals=[];
private chemintmp=[];
private chemin=[];
private noeud1 = {
    'x':0,
    'y':0,
    'dist':0
};
private noeudproche = {
    'x':0,
    'y':0,
    'dist':0
};

private startPos=[0, 0];
private goalPos=[];

private m_aStarInstance: AStar.AStarFinder;
private m_grid: AStar.Grid;
private m_pathway;

private matrice=[
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        ];

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams,
          public cartProvider: MycartProvider) {
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
      this.defineGoalPos();
  }

    defineGoalPos(){
        while(this.goals.length != 0){
            for (let i of this.goals) {
                this.goalPos=i;
                let matrix = this.matrice;
                this.m_grid = new AStar.Grid(matrix);
                let diagonalMovement = true;
                this.m_aStarInstance = new AStar.AStarFinder(this.m_grid, diagonalMovement);
                this.m_pathway = this.m_aStarInstance.findPath(this.startPos, this.goalPos);

                if(this.noeudproche.dist != 0){

                    let x1= this.goalPos[0];
                    let y1= this.goalPos[1];

                    this.noeud1.x = x1;
                    this.noeud1.y = y1;
                    this.noeud1.dist = this.m_pathway.length;

                    if(this.noeud1.dist < this.noeudproche.dist){
                        this.newgoals.push([this.noeudproche.x, this.noeudproche.y]);
                        this.noeudproche.x = this.noeud1.x;
                        this.noeudproche.y = this.noeud1.y;
                        this.noeudproche.dist = this.noeud1.dist;
                        this.chemintmp.splice(0,1);
                        this.chemintmp.push(this.m_pathway);
                    }
                    else{
                        this.newgoals.push([this.noeud1.x, this.noeud1.y]);
                    }

                }
                else{
                    let x_proche= this.goalPos[0];
                    let y_proche= this.goalPos[1];

                    this.noeudproche.x = x_proche;
                    this.noeudproche.y = y_proche;
                    this.noeudproche.dist = this.m_pathway.length;
                    this.chemintmp.splice(0,1);
                    this.chemintmp.push(this.m_pathway);
                }
            }
            this.chemin.push(this.chemintmp);
            this.goals=this.newgoals;
            this.newgoals=[];
            this.startPos=[this.noeudproche.x, this.noeudproche.y];
            this.noeud1.x = 0;
            this.noeud1.y = 0;
            this.noeud1.dist = 0;
            this.noeudproche.x = 0;
            this.noeudproche.y = 0;
            this.noeudproche.dist = 0;
            this.chemintmp=[];
            //console.log(this.chemin);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: please insert the code snippet regarding your final problem - people are not going to search for it in your github

Comment: Hi Skandix,
That's the problem, I don't know how to code the "6)" point of my post (So I have nothing), that's why I asked advices ^^'

Comment: well, this is not the place to let others code something for you. You show us what you have tried so far and then we try to improve it *based* on that.

Comment: I don't ask any code! I just ask advice regarding what I explain 

For exemple ("You should take a look to ***) ?